# CSS: Cant get sidebar working properly

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am trying to get a sidebar working. But it is not letting the #main Section go along side the sidebar.
Instead you get the sidebar, followed by the main (puts it below). :(

Also, if you can get a solution where sidebar may/maynot be present, and the main will fill the space, that would be great.

Below is what I am trying to get.

[image: CSS Desired layout]

Here is some of the relevant CSS

```
#main 
{
    margin: 0 0 0 100px; /* This is my way of indenting it over the sidebar (not dynamic to no sidebar being present*/
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;   
}

ul#sidebar
{ 
    width: auto;
    /* float:left; */
    font-size: 95%;
    word-spacing: -0.1em;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 1px; 
}
```

The footer seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set widths using % and float the sidebar left...

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
   <div class="main">Main</div>
</div>

.wrapper {width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
.sidebar {width:8%; float:left; margin-right:2%;}
.main {width:90%; float:left;}
```

Comment: I think this has done the trick. I disabled my CSS to see the pure effects from your CSS. Will renable bit by bit to intergrate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a margin on main, you just need to either float main to the right, or float the navbar to the left.  I notice you have a float: left commented out for the ul; was that not working for you?

Comment: It was allowing them to go side by side, with just sidebar floating. However the form box was going underneath it, plus the positioning I was having to do by having `padding:50px 20px 10px 1px; just to get it remotely close. It looked tacky to say the least. EDIT. Oh and float right on the main is just placing it under the footer. :(

Comment: Ah, don't forget to clear the float after them both.  There are multiple ways to do that, but I often just put `<div class="clear"></div>` after groups of things that are arranged horizontally, with the clear class being something like:

`div.clear { clear: both }`

Answer (score 1):

Float left on both is my usual method.  However, you need to remember to clear float after the two floated elements, otherwise you get overlap like you mentioned on the footer.  I usually handle this by doing an empty div with `clear:both` defined.

I can't say enough about [Grids](http://www.960.gs).  There's both the standard 960 and fluid grid options.  Then, there's no worries about floats, overlap, or wrapping.  It's just done for you.  Then you can spend development time on the really important stuff.